# Edit default shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Im having an issue with editing the DefaultSharedPreferences.
Indded, I have a method that I call regularly and I would like to use its input to edit the default shared preferences.

Here is what I tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
 mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_location_default), stringCoordinates);
    editor.commit();
```

And here are my concerned Strings:

```
<!-- Key name for storing location in SharedPreferences [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="pref_location_key" translatable="false">location</string>

<!-- Default postal code for location preference [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="pref_location_default" translatable="false">-34.8799074,174.7565664</string>
```

Can someone help me please?

Thx!

Comment: aren't you supposed to use R.string.pref_location_key on your editor.putString?

Comment: Geez...Silly mistake indeed!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line :

```
 mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),MODE_PRIVATE);
```